# ir para a próxima div excluindo outro elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide fade ativa"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> <span>Este é 1</span> </div>
  <div class="slide fade"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> <span>Este é 2</span> </div>
  <div class="slide fade"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> <span>Este é 3</span> </div>
  <nav>
  <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
  <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

preciso correr dentro da div.slider, todos, e apenas, divs.slide excluindo os buttons do loop. Como faço?

O objetivo é criar um slide em que, quando chegar na ultima div, retonar o loop à primeira div.
Da forma abaixo que estou fazendo, não está dando certo.

```
const blocos = $("div.slider div.slide");

function startslider() {  

  ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")

  if (!$(ativa).next().length) {
    ativa = blocos.first()
  }

   $(ativa)
      .removeClass("ativa")
      .next()
      .addClass("ativa")

   setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
}

setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei o `data-slide` nas `<div>`s para fazer a interação

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide fade ativa" data-slide="1"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> <span>Este é 1</span> </div>
    <div class="slide fade" data-slide="2"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> <span>Este é 2</span> </div>
    <div class="slide fade" data-slide="3"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> <span>Este é 3</span> </div>
    <nav>
        <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
        <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Aqui no `Jquery`,como já coloquei no comentário, você pode definir a animação de acordo com seu projeto, para o `<button class="anterior">` basta fazer o cálculo inverso

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.proximo').click(function(){
        var slide = $('.ativa').attr('data-slide');
        var proximo = parseInt(slide)+1;
        $('[data-slide="'+slide+'"]').removeClass('ativa');
        $('[data-slide="'+slide+'"]').hide();//aqui você usa fadeIn, fadeOut, de acordo com seu projeto
        if(proximo>($('div.slide').length)){
          $('[data-slide="1"]').show();//aqui você usa fadeIn, fadeOut, de acordo com seu projeto
            $('[data-slide="1"]').addClass('ativa');
        }else{
          $('[data-slide="'+proximo+'"]').show();//aqui você usa fadeIn, fadeOut, de acordo com seu projeto
         $('[data-slide="'+proximo+'"]').addClass('ativa');
        }
    });
</script>
```